# How to deal with cp1252 encoding while Spliting a String contains Japanese Characters

Tags: java, character-encoding

I am reading a csv file line by line and delimiting each line on the basis of 
    tab delimiter.There is a line in file like  :-

"\"255U-2968RYE\"    \"Organization\"    \"ＳＭＢＣ日興証券 株式会社\"   \"2968RYE\"

I used split function format split("\t(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)",-1). In my view 
   split function should return a String array of size 4. But it is not working as I am 
   expecting. I tried to change encoding type in eclipse and used different-2 like utf-8,
   ISO-8859-1 But did not work. File is of csv format. I am reading it using CSV open 
    source api. as shown below.

```
    String read[];      
    int row = 0;
    int columns = 0;
    int totalElement = 0;
    String msg = null;  
    int cols = (int) Double. parseDouble(totalColumns);

    try
    {
    CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(filePath),'\n');
    if(titleAllowed.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"))
        reader.readNext();
    while((read=(reader.readNext()))!=null)         
    {   
        row++;      
        if(row==1)
        {               
        columns = (read[0].split(",(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)",-1)).length;

         if(cols !=columns)
         {
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Columns not matched as mentioned in checkList");
             return false;
         }

        }       
        if((columns!=0)&&(columns!=read[0].split(",(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)",-1).length))
        {
            msg = "Error exists in line "+row;
            return false;
        }
        if(!read[0].equals(""))
            totalElement+=(read[0].split(",(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)",-1)).length;                     
    }
    reader.close();
    }catch(Exception e)
    {           
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
    if(null!=msg)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, msg);
    }       
    return (totalElement==row*columns);
```

Correct answer is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: What encoding is the file in and how are you reading it? Also, put your code in backticks.

Comment: I have added code for your information @ Karol S

Comment: Another question: how does the line look in the file actually? does it look `"\"255U-2968RYE\" \"Organization\" \"ＳＭＢＣ日興証券 株式会社\" \"2968RYE\"` or does it look `"255U-2968RYE" "Organization" "ＳＭＢＣ日興証券 株式会社" "2968RYE"`? Also, encoding in Eclipse pertrains only to the source code.

Comment: It looks like as second one in your comment

Comment: Try replacing `new FileReader(filePath)` with `new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(filePath), "SHIFT-JIS"))`